# Microsoft.XMLHTTP clearing cookie in Lotusscript

Tags: cookies, com, lotus-notes, lotusscript, xmlhttprequest

I have a Lotusscript agent that creates a Microsoft.XMLHTTP object 
This object access a servlet and receives transactions since the last time I asked.

This is what is done:

```
Set objHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")     
objHttp.open "POST", theUrl, False, "", ""  
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", specific_for_customer  
objHttp.send(theReq)    
headers = objHttp.getAllResponseHeaders()   
response = objHttp.responseText     
'...do the stuff...     
Set objHttp=Nothing
```

It works very good while you are keeping the session open and asks questions.
But if as in my case the intention is to run this agent every 5 minutes I got problem.

I am closing down the object as expected.
When I start the agent again the servlet dont accept my access since I am having a session cookie in my request(and it is not accepted).

In my world that session cookie the servlet and my code agreed on 5 minutes ago should be cleared out when I did the Set objHttp=Nothing.
I can not find the cookie either.
I guess thats in some special/strange way the Domino Agent manager keeps the cookie(but where) and try to use it when I am connecting again.

While in session with the servlet I can find the value for the cookie, but not when I am connect the next time the agent runs.

The only way to get establish a session again is to restart the agent manager.

I have tried several things find and delete the cookie(cant find it).

In my way to troubleshoot this I even copied the agent and then did run that agent, and I dont get access to the servlet, so the agent manager is the suspect here...

Maybe someone had a similar problem.

So..

- How can I clear cookies from the agent manager that in the first
  place should been cleared when I closed down the XML-object
- How can I clear the agent manager "memory" to forget about everything
- How can I restart the agent manager from code or scheduled

Hope for some help in some way

Answer (score 3):

Setting objHTTP=nothing only dereferences the object. It does not unload the DLL that provided that object or other DLLs that it loaded (which in this case is a good sized chunk of Microsoft's IE-based stack). It does not clear the memory that these DLLs allocated to that object. And since the AMGR is the process that loaded those DLLs, and AMGR is still running, it's pretty much the same as if you started a browser, connected to that site, opened a bunch of other browser tabs, closed the tab with the session cookie, waited 5 minutes, then opened up a new tab and went back to that site. The cookie is still there.

Setting the objHTTP=nothing is just like closing the tab.  Microsoft thinks they're doing you a favor by doing this.  Just like with a browser, the best way to deal with this is to log out of the site. If the site offers a logout URL, connect to it before you set objHTTP=nothing. That should get the server to invalidate the cookie for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was guessing, but hoped not to be true ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could go and switch to Java for the [HTTP Communication](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8BQNWN). The sample in the link has reusable code and wraps it nicely into LS2J. Also: it will run on all platforms

Comment: I was trying to awoid to change direction since the "other stuff" is already there...  I check on your link when your blog is back up again.

Comment: More of the "other stuff" containing headache doesn't lower the pain. Best advice for dealing with a dead horse (like my server with dead harddrives): unmount.